# Kotlin equivalent of Groovy Gradle file

Tags: kotlin, gradle, groovy

With Android Studio "Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1" Kotlin is the default for Gradle files. An example of part of one of my Groovy build.gradle files is:

```
dependencies
{   implementation files('libs/jsch-0.1.54.jar')
    implementation project(':potpourri')
```

The correcponding setting.gradle file is:

```
include ':app'
include ':potpourri'

project(':potpourri').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../Potpourri/app')
```

My question is: What is the Kotlin equivalents for the potpourri module?

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/migrating_from_groovy_to_kotlin_dsl.html

Comment: Thank you for your comment but it does not appear to address the 'project' issue

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking, exactly. You mention the potpourri module, but it's hard to come up with any code for that with this little information. Are you perhaps just looking for the kts equivalent of the code that you shared? And also, what do you mean by the 'project' issue?

Comment: The/my problem is that there does not appear to be a 'project' statement a Kotlin kts file

Comment: Ah, so you're specifically looking for the kts equivalent of `implementation project(':potpourri')`? This should work: `implementation(project(":potpourri"))`. See also https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies_between_subprojects.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
dependencies {
    implementation(files("libs/jsch-0.1.54.jar"))
    implementation(project(":potpourri"))
}
```

With in settings.gradle.kts:

```
include(":app")
include(":potpourri")

project(":potpourri").projectDir = File(settingsDir, "../Potpourri/app")
```

More information about dependecies between sub projects here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies_between_subprojects.html

Comment: THAT'S IT!!! It was removing the "new" that was the key - along with the other migratory issues, ie, using brackets & etc

Comment: That's great! Could you please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer? :-)